# 'No data to display' message when gridstore is loaded Ext JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

`Extjs 4.3.1`I have a grid that is being loaded with a javascript array. The array is populated but when the page is loaded nothing appears. When you click the refresh button in the `Ext.toolbar` dock the items appear.

How do I make the data load when the page is rendered and not when the refresh button is selected?

[image: Example]

**Code**

```
var grid = [],
        title = 'Topics List',
        gridHeight = 600,
        uniqueId = 'topics',
        dSort = 'modified',
        dSortOrder = 'DESC';
    var items = [];

    Ext.define('Model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'title', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'description', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'updated', type: 'date'},
        {name: 'state', type: 'string'}
    ]
    });
    var gridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Model',
        autoload: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: url,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'entry',
                idProperty: 'title'
            }
        },
            fields: [{
                name: 'title',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'description',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'updated',
                type: 'date',
                format: 'm/d/Y'
            }, {
                name: 'state',
                type: 'string'
            }],
            sorters: [{
                property: 'updated',
                direction: 'DESC'
            },{
                property: 'title',
                direction: 'DESC'
                }
            ],
            listeners: {
                render: function () {
                    gridStore.load();
                }
            }

        });

        var searchField = new SearchField({store: gridStore, width: 300});
        var filters = {
            ftype: 'filters',
            // encode and local configuration options defined previously for easier reuse
            encode: false, // json encode the filter query
            local: true   // defaults to false (remote filtering)

        };
        var searchBar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
            cls: 'x-toolbar-top',
            items: ['Search: ', ' ', searchField, {xtype: 'tbfill'}]
        });
        var clearButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Clear Filter Data',
            handler: function () {
                grid[uniqueId].filters.clearFilters();
            }
        });
        var openButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Open Topics',
            handler: function () {
                var filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.getFilter('state');
                if (!filter) {
                    filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.addFilter({
                        type: 'string',
                        dataIndex: 'state'
                    });
                }
                filter.setActive(true);
                filter.setValue('Open/Current');
            }
        });
        var holdButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'On Hold Topics',
            handler: function () {
                var filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.getFilter('state');
                if (!filter) {
                    filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.addFilter({
                        type: 'string',
                        dataIndex: 'state'
                    });
                }
                filter.setActive(true);
                filter.setValue('Hold');
            }
        });
        var closedButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Closed Topics',
            handler: function () {
                var filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.getFilter('state');
                if (!filter) {
                    filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.addFilter({
                        type: 'string',
                        dataIndex: 'state'
                    });
                }
                filter.setActive(true);
                filter.setValue('Archived/Closed');
            }
        });

        var createColumns = function () {

            var columns = [{
                text: 'Title',
                width: 260,
                dataIndex: 'title',
                filterable: true
            }, {
                text: 'Description',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'description',
                filter: {
                    type: 'string'
                    // specify disabled to disable the filter menu
                    //, disabled: true
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Status',
                width: 100,
                dataIndex: 'state',
                filter: {
                    active: true,
                    type: 'list',
                    //value: 'Open/Current',
                    options: ['Open/Current', 'Archived/Closed', 'Hold']

                }
            }, {
                text: 'Modified',
                width: 90,
                dataIndex: 'updated',
                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                format: 'm/d/Y',
                filter: true
            }];

            return columns;
        };
        grid[uniqueId] = Ext.create('Ext.grid.GridPanel', {
            renderTo: uniqueId,
            store: gridStore,
            tbar: [
                searchBar,
                openButton,
                holdButton,
                closedButton,
                clearButton
            ],
            columns: createColumns(),
            enableColumnHide: true,
            enableColumnMove: true,
            height: gridHeight,
            title: title,
            loadMask: true,
            features: [filters],
            dockedItems: [Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Paging', {
                dock: 'bottom',
                store: gridStore,
                displayInfo: true
            })],
        listeners: {
            render: function () {
                gridStore.load();
            }
        }
        });
```

**JSON ex**

```
"entry": [{
        "title": "Alternative Methods",
        "shortTitle": "LCRs",
        "description": "This project is a carryover from the 2017 effort.",
        "govStatus": "Progress",
        "state": "Open/Current",
        "dateCreated": "",
        "targetComplete": "",
        "updated": "2017-08-14T10:58:19"
    },...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the grid is not loading, then what do you get when you add a listener to the gridPanel for 'onRender'? Is the data from your store available on the grid render?

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-render

Comment: I changed the code a bit so that the gridstore loads using the `ajax` call and not memory and also added a listener on the gridpanel to load the store but i still don't get any data loaded until after the refresh button is hit

Comment: weird. is it possible that the data is being loaded after the render so it doesn't get attached to the grid? also, i took your above code and wrote this fiddle. see it if helps. I commented out a bit of your toolbar buttons. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2715

Answer (score 0):

Populate the store before creating the grid using ajax or store.load(). What is happening in your case is that, the store has not finished loading by the time grid is rendered. That is why on refreshing the data is there and not on render.